# node.js - koa: generator don't go next

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I have a simple object where I pass a parameter, then I want to find all document in my collections and stamp it. This is my custom object:

```
var db = require('../lib/db');
function Widget(n,l,c,o,t,p) {

    this.name = n;
    this.label = l;
    this.class = c;
    this.order = o;
    this.template = t;
    this.params = p;

    if(this.params != null) {
        var a = getValue(this.params);
        a.next();
     }
}
function *getValue(p){
    var Object = require("./sections");

    console.log("1");
    try {
        var objects = yield Object.find({}).exec();
    }
    catch(err){ 
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("2");
    console.log("obj:" + objects);
}
module.exports = Widget;
```

and this is sections.js

```
var db = require('../lib/db');
var schema = new db.Schema(
{
    title:          String,
    parent:         { type: db.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'sections' },
    child:          [{ type: db.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'sections' }],
    updated_on:     Date,
    created_on:     Date
});
module.exports = db.model( 'sections', schema );
```

I create the object in this way:

```
var widget  = new Widget("text","Titiolo",0,0,"text.html","sections");
```

on my console I see only "1" not 2 or "objects:" why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has nothing to do with `koa`. this is just how generators work. `.next()` evaluates the code up until the next `yield` function. because you have 1 `yield` in your generator function, you'll need to call `.next()` twice to finish evaluating the entire function including the last two `console.log()`s

also, your try/catch block doesn't do anything.